# VS2017でSytem.Messaging で、名前空間 'System' に存在しませんとなる

Tags: c#

VS2017 C#で、メッセージキューを使いたく、using System.Messaging;を宣言したのですが、
「名前空間の名前 'Messaging' が名前空間 'System' に存在しません。。」となります。
いろいろ、調べたのですが、わかりません。尚、開発は.NET Coreですが、コンソールアプリでも
同じエラーが出ます。解決方法をご存知の方、ご指導お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

System.Messaging(MSMQ)はプラットフォーム非依存ではないため、.NET Coreではサポートされないとなっています。
[Is System.Messaging.dll not available in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49044257/9014308)

ただし、誰かが実験的に移植しているようです。
[Experimental.System.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Experimental.System.Messaging/)
Windows環境下でなら使えるかもしれません。

Comment: ターゲットマシンは、不運にもLinuxですが、メッセージキューは諦めます。調べたところ、キューを使う例がありましたので、試したところ、うまく動きました。これからLinuxで動くか確かめます。

Comment: Thank you so much.